# How to update SharedPreferences variable automatically?

Tags: java, android

Supposedly i have a sharedpreferences float value called floatValue. How do i set floatValue automatically to 0 when the device detects its a new day? Like for example today is 2/1/17, and the value of floatValue is 1250.23. Is it possible for this to be reset to 0 and that my textView will display 0 such that when the user wakes up in the morning the next day, he will notice the textview's text is 0.

I'm sorry for the indentations. Basically, I initialize newTodayFloatValue to 0 as i need todayValueToBeAdded to append into newTodayFloatValue. Then i save this value into SharedPreferences! But i'm hoping this can be resetted after date_changed.

```
 float newTodayFloatValue = 0;
 tvTodayFloatValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.todayfloatValueTextView);
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    float todayValueToBeAdded = intent1.getFloatExtra("strValueToBeAdded", 0.0f);
    final SharedPreferences totalTodayfloatValue = getSharedPreferences("totalTodayfloatValue", 0);
    newTodayFloatValue = totalTodayfloatValue.getFloat("totalTodayfloatValue", 0);
    newTodayFloatValue = newTodayFloatValue + todayValueToBeAdded;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = totalTodayfloatValue.edit();
    editor.putFloat("totalTodayfloatValue", newTodayFloatValue);
    editor.commit();
    tvTodayFloatValue.setText(String.valueOf(newTodayFloatValue));
```

Comment: Are you using service for this?

Comment: Nope! I am technically stuck because i don't know what the approach is for this situation!

Comment: any code that you have of your activity where I can put chages and show you ?

Comment: Added the codes already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a broadcast receiver with action

> "android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"

It will trigger whenever the date is changed either automatically (because the date actually has changed) or explicitly by the user.

For this Broadcast to be received even when your app is not running, you will need to declare it within your manifest with the mentioned Intent-Filter.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".DateChangeReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then within the Receiver, you can make a change in the SharedPreferences

```
public class DateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("YOUR_INT", 0);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow this isn't exactly working out for me! I understand your code and the logic behind your codes, but my textview keeps displaying the previous day's float value. What should be the approach now?

Comment: Can you post your current code? The Manifest, the Receiver and the Activity/Fragment/Class where you read the SharedPreferences?

Comment: Thanks so much! Your comment got me to really go take a relook at the manifest, and turns out, it was the position of intent-filter code that got my application to be not working! It's solved now!

Comment: Cool, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

There are Android "broadcasts" for such events, like time changed  ( ACTION_TIME_CHANGED )  or when the date changes ( ACTION_DATE_CHANGED
ACTION ).

See the corresponding [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) for further reading. And [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) you can find information how to work with broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is much easier way to achieve this effect. I would write a methods `getFloatValue(...)` , and `setFloatValue` , in method `setFloatValue` you should update not only `floatValue` in `SharedPreferences` but `floatValueLastModification` also.

Then in `getFloatValue` you should compare `floatValueLastModification` with current time and return 0 if it is previous day.

Of course since you do it this way you should access this `floatValue` only through these methods.

I think it will be much easier to read and understand such code.